# Ruby class methods calling it twice?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

```
class Tests
  def self.test1
    'This is the First'
  end

  def self.test2
    'This is the second'
  end
end
puts Tests.test1.test2
```

I keep getting an error

```
undefined method `test2' for "This is the First":String (NoMethodError).
```

I am assuming its not possible to call the second class method. However I am doing coding something which tells me that is possible. Can anyone confirm or help fix this?

Comment: This is called a "fluent interface" so link to the blog post where this was popularized and historical context on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return `self` from each method, you can chain them infinite number of times :)

**Note**: I've added `puts` to each method, because otherwise all method would do is returning `self`.

```
class Tests
  def self.test1
    puts 'This is the First'
    self
  end

  def self.test2
    puts 'This is the second'
    self
  end
end

Tests.test1.test2
#=> This is the First
#=> This is the second
```

Basically you perform some logic in method, and when it's done, you return the object itself, so that each chained method call gets called on the  object, not on the result of previous method (when there were no `self` returned).

Comment: Thanks, putting self at the end allowed me to chain call methods, which is actually what I wanted (didnt know thats what I wanted at the time).

Comment: @Hayasama note, that  I've added `puts` to each method, because otherwise all method would do is returning `self`. Glad to help, make sure to accept the answer since it worked (look for a checkmark below the answer score)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to build a "fluent interface"

The basic idea is that when all methods on an object return `self` then they can be chained together without repeating the receiver. This idea has been popularized by Martin Flower in this blog post but goes all the way back to Smalltalk's `;` method chaining syntax.

- https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

This is unrelated to class methods actually and works just the same way for instance methods. Here is an example that passes the chain from class to instance side

```
class Lorem
  def self.ipsum
    Lorem.new # passing the change from class to instance side
  end
  def dolor
    self
  end
  def sit
    self
  end
  def amet
    self
  end
end

Lorem.ipsum.dolor.sit.amet
```

Comment: Didn't know it's called `fluent interface`, +1!. P.S. There is not `class methods` in Ruby, I am sure you know - it is all instance methods :)

Comment: @andreydeineko hahaha!

Comment: Smalltalk's method cascading (`;`) is more like `Lorem.ipsum.tap(&:dolor).tap(&:sit).tap(&:amet)` – it doesn't require the methods to return the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with those definitions; you're defining two class methods on your `Tests` class. This is equivalent to your code:

```
string = Tests.test1
# => string = "This is the First"
string.test2
# => (undefined method)
```

Since `test2` isn't defined on the `String` class, you'll get the `undefined method 'test2' for (...):String` error.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure why you want to chain the method calls here, you can invoke those separately.

```
Tests.test1
=> "This is the First"

Tests.test2
=> "This is the second"
```

short explanation of the error, first method **test1** returns a string, which has no method **test2** defined under it which results to

> error undefined method `test2' for "This is the First":String (NoMethodError)